# linux-swap turns swap off during turn off

Tags: swap

When I found my system being too slow, I created a linux-swap with the help of gparted. It has helped me highly, providing a reliable processing speed without any blackening of my screen. But whenever I turn off my system the partition turns to swap off mode. So whenever I turn on my system again, I need to swap on my linux-swap. I am tired of waking it up every time when I start off my system. Is there any way to make my linux-swap to  swap on itself as and when the system boots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

You will be asked for your password. Then, add a line to the end of the file:

```
[swap partition]       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Replace `[swap partition]` by the name of the partition, e.g. `/dev/sda5`. Also, be careful not to accidentally change the other lines in the file. Save and reboot.

---

About nano, this should be written in the lower part of the terminal:

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (an O as in *oven*, not a zero) to save the file
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit from nano.

Comment: I added that to my answer.

Comment: Press CTRL + O to save the file. Then, press CTRL + X to exit `nano`.